# Why does text input onchange submit fire form submit

Tags: javascript, html

I'm unable to find information on why this code fires the form submit when the input changes:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" onchange="submit();">
</form>
```

I always thought that it has to be something like this:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" onchange="this.form.submit();">
</form>
```

`this.form.submit();` and `submit();` do the same thing (at least in Chrome).

But the input DOM element doesn't have a function `submit()` defined. Why does this work?

"Browser magic" isn't a sufficient answer to that.

Comment: Because your form does not have attribute `name="form"`

Comment: Aside from the problem - this is yet another reason why `onX` attributes should never be used - their scope isn't obvious.

Comment: @Justinas would you mind elaborating on this?

Comment: _"But the change of the input will NOT do it, but instead do a form submit, omitting what is defined in onsubmit of the form"_ - yes, of course. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event: _"the event is not sent to the form when a script calls the form.submit() method directly"_

Comment: Ok, so `submit();` and `this.form.submit();` actually do the same thing. Check.

That does not explain, why just `submit();` in the `onchange` of the input is working.

Comment: That's because how JavaScript works, when resolving identifiers. It first looks in the current scope, and then it moves further up. That's why you can for example do `alert("foobar")` at any nesting level of your code, without having a function by that name defined in your local scope. Because the function is not found there, it looks for one "further up", and eventually finds `window.alert`. With the submit method on a form field, it works the same way.

Answer (score 0):

i think because you are using onchange() in javascript its an event listener, so if you enter an input, it will fire because it noticed a change in the form, you should use onclick() when submitted then it will fire at that moment. you should actually add it in the form tag not on the input like this

Comment: But... I don't want to submit the form when clicking anywhere in the form.I want to submit the form, when the value of the input changes, not when I click the input.

Comment: then try to work on onchange that gets when events has changes, then a form to verify validation if inputs field are changed and not empty , then submit form @Akerus

Comment: This isn't about how to submit a form. It is about why `onchange="submit();"` works, when the input-element doesn't have a function `submit()` defined.

Answer (score -1):

The **submit()** function is not defined for the input element in a form. This is because the **submit()** function is only defined for the form element itself. Therefore, calling **this.form.submit()** or **SubmitForm(this.form)** is the correct way to submit a form using JavaScript.

The error message "submit is not a function" occurs when the name or id of a form control is "submit", which masks the form's submit method. Renaming the button to something else, such as "btnSubmit", will resolve the issue.

Comment: But the thing is, `<input type="text" onchange="submit();">` actually submits the form it is nested in when a value is entered and the focus is lost. This should not work, no?

Comment: The onchange="submit();" attribute in an input element should not submit the form it is nested in when a value is entered and the focus is lost. However, it seems to work in some cases, which may be due to browser-specific behavior or other factors. It is generally recommended to use the onchange="this.form.submit();" or onchange="SubmitForm(this.form);" syntax to submit a form using JavaScript, as these are the correct ways to do so.

If this is the case, to avoid losing focus, call two actions: onchange="submit(); this.form.submit();"> in the same call.

Comment: And that is exactly my question: Why does `onchange="submit();"` work? Just saying its "browser magic" is kind of not a real answer to that question.